# Assigning 2 Time variables to time values in 2 Cells using VBA script throws type mismatch error 13

Tags: vba, excel, time

Am trying to compare system time with Start and End times stored in adjacent columns. The below code worked fine for sometime until I changed some code (but reverted back to old code because it was not working). After reverting to old code the comparison is not working and throwing a 'type mismatch' error '13'. Also, the value of 'z' after the For loop is becoming 0 due to which am not getting the correct output.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub MyBtn_Click()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim w As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim tm1 As Date
    Dim tm2 As Date
    Dim tm3 As Date
    tm1 = Time
    w = Weekday(Date, vbSunday)
    w = w + 2
    For i = 2 To 32
        tm2 = TimeValue(Cells(i, 1).Text) ' this is the line throwing 'type mismatch'
        tm3 = TimeValue(Cells(i, 2).Text)
        If tm1 >= tm2 And tm1 <= tm3 Then
            z = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
        myMsgBox i ' here i = 32, don't know why
        myMsgBox z ' z = 0 for some reason
        MsgBox Cells(z, w), vbOKOnly, "Result" ' does not give the cell contents as z=0

End Sub
```

Comment: show please content of `Cells(i, 1).Text` and `Cells(i, 2).Text` cells

Comment: @simoco - for eg., valueS in cell(2,1) = 6:00:00 AM and cell(2,2) = 6:24:00 AM .... i checked comparison of these in a sample code and it worked fine. But when I put in the For loop it throws type mismatch error. And when I say 'Exit For' I expect 'i' value to be the row-number that matches the system time, so how would it be 32? and how is z = 0 when I have assigned i value to it?

Comment: Put a break point at the z = i and you will see that that line never executes. Or step with F8 to see what happens line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic did the trick-

```
If IsDate(Cells(i, 1).Value) And IsDate(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
```

... but still, I got a run-time error as z became 0. So I just tried using .Text (put it back again) instead of .Value and now the program's working!

so this is what it looks like -

```
For i = 2 To 32
If IsDate(Cells(i, 1).Text) And IsDate(Cells(i, 2).Text) Then
   time2 = TimeValue(Cells(i, 1).Text)
   time3 = TimeValue(Cells(i, 2).Text)
   If tm1 >= time2 And tm1 <= time3 Then
      z = i
      Exit For
   End If
 End If
Next i
```

Comment: Generally if someone helped you with your problem you should credit them for it by accepting their answer. The only difference between this and my answer is that using `.text` worked better than using `.value`. It would be good to note that as a comment under my answer so the next person sees that.

Comment: I'm curious why .text is working better than .value; is it because it is comparing text strings and not comparing date values? It would help to know what was in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the value in the cell is convertible to time. If not you'll get the mismatch message. Also I always use `.value` instead of `.text`

```
'declare as dates to ensure that the values are treated as dates and not as something else
dim tm1 as Date, tm2 as Date, tm3 as Date

For i = 2 To 32
    'test to make sure the cells have date/time values
    If IsDate(Cells(i, 1).Value) And IsDate(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
        tm2 = TimeValue(Cells(i, 1).Value) 
        tm3 = TimeValue(Cells(i, 2).Value)
        If tm1 >= tm2 And tm1 <= tm3 Then
            Z = i
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

You'll need to step through the code slowly using F8 and examine the value of your variables at each step to determine whether the code is working properly. This code will avoid the MisMatch error but you will need to check the data to make sure it works the way you want it to.

As to your second question: 
i = 32 because that's the last value it was set in the for loop.

And z = 0 because the condition was never met in your if statement: `If tm1 >= tm2 And tm1 <= tm3 Then`

Comment: Could someone please help me out? 
@D_Bester: I used .value instead of .text but still it is throwing type mismatch error. The very same code worked twice or thrice but now it is not at all working. Also, is there any other way to do the comparisons of time values?